# ¿Como eliminar el circulo central del radio buttom en CSS?

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes programadores,

Mi consulta, como dice en el titulo, se puede eliminar el punto central del radio buttom? Me gustaría hacer que quede solo el borde del radio buttom.

```css
#a {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="radio" name="radio">
```

Comment: No entiendo lo de *el punto central....* ¿puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: Un radio buttom visualmente en html es un borde circular y un circulo completo en medio en caso de estar checked, mi intencion es quitar el circulo del centro y dejar solo el borde en caso de estar checked. Nose si se me permita hacer eso o tendre que crear mi propio radio buttom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver si esto te sirve:

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  transition: 0.2s all linear;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

input:checked {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Selecione una opcion</h2>
<input type="radio" id="opcion" name="uno" value="opcion">
<label for="opcion">Opcion1</label>
```

Definiendo el valor del `border` en el `input:checked` puedes modificar el grosor del botón.

Comment: En efecto mi estimado, era lo que buscaba, muchisimas gracias